# Orbit and control distance from object in 3D

Tags: 3d, rotation, orbit, godot-3

I'm stumped on a key part of my game project, built in Godot 3.5.2.

I'm trying to have my player character be able to rotate around an object using A and D, as well as get closer and farther from it along a line using W and S. I've exhausted my personal knowledge on Godot trying to figure this out and I'll post my code below.

```
var move_base = .05
    
var move_dist = (Input.get_action_strength("move_down") - Input.get_action_strength("move_up")) * move_base
var move_orb = (Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")) * move_base
    
# Rotation variables
# Subtract origin point from target's position
var pivot_radius = Vector3.ZERO - target.global_translation
    
var pivot_transform = Transform(transform.basis, target.global_translation)

# Rotate around target
transform = pivot_transform.rotated(Vector3(0, 1, 0), move_orb).translated(pivot_radius)
```

I believe that if I can modify pivot radius to allow me to move along the radius it would work perfectly fine, but I'm bad when it comes to geometry and math.

I've also attached a picture to clarify what I'm trying to achieve if it helps at all. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, work in global coordinates.

You are using `target.global_translation` which is global coordinates, but you are setting `transform` which isn't, instead it is relative to the parent node.

---

*I will not go for a clever solution, but for one that is easy to follow.*

We want to rotate the position of the player character `global_transform.origin` around the position of the distant object `target.global_translation.origin`.

So the vector we want to rotate is:

```
var vector_to_rotate := global_transform.origin - target.global_translation.origin
```

To rotate it we are to need a rotation axis, you are using `Vector3(0, 1, 0)`, so I will use `Vector3.UP`. And I believe `move_orb` is the rotation angle. *You might want to express it in terms of an angular velocity and use `delta` so it is frame rate independent, but I digress.*

We rotate it like this:

```
var rotated_vector := vector_to_rotate.rotate(Vector3.UP, move_orb)
```

So we can compute the new position:

```
global_transform.origin = target.global_transform.origin + rotated_vector
```

---

Ah, but you want to control the distance too! So, instead we will get direction and distance. For example, like this:

```
var vector := global_transform.origin - target.global_translation.origin
var direction := vector.normalized()
var distance := vector.length()
```

*You could also use `direction_to` and `distance_to`. Or you could normalize by dividing the vector over its length (but careful with division by zero).*

Then we rotate the `direction`:

```
direction = direction.rotate(Vector3.UP, move_orb)
```

Change the `distance`:

```
distance += move_dist
```

*Again, you could define a velocity and use `delta`, but you do you.*

And we get the new position:

```
global_transform.origin = target.global_transform.origin + direction * distance
```

---

You can have the player character facing the target with a `look_at`:

```
look_at(target.global_transform.origin, Vector3.UP)
```

And that would account for the rotation.

Comment: Honestly I just did what you suggested in the last point and my final code ended up being:
var move_orbit = (Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")) * move_base
var move_dist = (Input.get_action_strength("move_down") - Input.get_action_strength("move_up")) * move_base
 
look_at(target.global_translation, Vector3(0, 1, 0))
 
# Modify velocity
velocity.x = move_orbit
velocity.z = move_dist
 
# Return velocity with modified angle to target.
return velocity.rotated(Vector3(0, 1, 0), get_rotation().y)